# MacBook Air not detecting any disk

Tags: bootcamp, ssd

**Early 2015 MacBook Air A1466**

I have Bootcamp (Windows 10 LTSC) and Paragon NTFS (if that matters) installed on this Mac. I was on Windows at the time but decided to sleep so I booted to MacOS (Monterey) and while it was on the loading bar (after entering password), I closed the lid. When I woke up, it was flashing a folder with a question mark. I went to Internet Recovery and checked Disk Utility to no avail; No drives (with view all drives). I checked diskutil list on the Terminal and still, no drives except the recovery itself (3 GB and another 1 GB). diskutil list shows 19 drives but they are only a few MBs and some are KBs in size. I also tried plugging in a USB and an SSD Enclosure with an m.2 Kingston inside (I used them both on this Mac before but the USB was NTFS so I had to use Paragon. The former is using exFat) but they too don't show up in diskutil list. I tried power-cycling the SSD too. Have yet to try it on a different Mac tho.

Apple Diagnostic says "There may be an issue with a storage device. Code VDH002"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a failed drive.
[Apple Diagnostics reference codes](https://support.apple.com/HT203747) says

> VDH002
> There may be an issue with a storage device.
> Contact Apple or take your computer to an AASP or Apple Store to find out which service and support options are available.